# Calculate the limit of the sequence given by the general term.

Tags: calculus

I need some help solving this limit of the sequence given by the general term, step by step. The problem is that I do something wrong and I don't get the answer from the book.
Solved similar examples, but this one is the last from this category and I didn't get proper result.
IDK what I did wrong.

$2.53$

$$ u_n = \left( \frac{3}{2}\right)^n \left(\frac{2^{n+1} -1}{3^{n+1}-1} \right) $$

So what I tried to do is: $$ \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n = \frac{3^n}{2^n} $$
so I had something like this:
$$ u_n = \left( \frac{3^n}{2^n}\right) \left(\frac{2^{n+1} -1}{3^{n+1}-1} \right) $$
$$ u_n = \left(\frac{3^{n}*2^{n+1} -3^{n}}{2^{n}*3^{n+1}-2^{n}} \right) $$
later tried:

$$ u_n = \left(\frac{3^{n}*2^{n}*2^1 -3^{n}}{2^{n}*3^{n}*3^1-2^{n}} \right)=? $$
What now? I have no clue, tried few things nothing good happened...
answer from book is: $\frac{2}{3}$

Can someone lead me, step by step to final result of this limit, from the book?

Sorry for my very average English... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distribution makes it not easy to visualize. Try this

$$ u_n = \left( \frac{3}{2}\right)^n \left(\frac{2^{n+1} -1}{3^{n+1}-1} \right)=\frac{3^n}{3^{n+1}-1}\cdot\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2^n} $$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n}{3^{n+1}-1}\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2^n} $$

You can go from here.